# Как понять какой класс вызывает метод?

Tags: java, android

Вот есть у меня допустим метод

```
public void setProgress(){}
```

Который могут вызывать 2 класса... и который должен по разному работать в зависимости от того какой класс его вызвал...

Как по нормальному определить какой класс вызывает метод?

Мне только придумалось передавать как параметр `1 или 2` и в методе лепить проверку... Но не уверен, что это лучшее решение...

Вот для наглядности мой код

```
private void writeFile(double contentLength, InputStream input, OutputStream output) {

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int totalRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;
        int incr = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            {
                totalRead += bytesRead;
                int progress = (int) (totalRead * (100 / contentLength));
                int result = progress % 10;
                if (result != 0 || progress != incr)
                    continue;
                if (progress < 100)
                    new ProcessBarNotification(context).updateProcessNotification(progress);
                incr += 10;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(MY_LOG, "writeFile " + e);
    }

    try {
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Он сейчас передает `progress` в `Notification` и в нем у меня отображается полоска прогресса, это все отлично работает если юзер получил `Notification` и в нем нажал на кнопку <kbd>Read</kbd> и пошла загрузка. Но если юзер хочет сделать загрузку открыв приложение и в приложении нажать на кнопку <kbd>Read</kbd> , то мне не нужно показывать прогресс в нотификации, я его буду показывать уже в приложении...

Значит мне нужно как то различать от куда вызывается этот метод...

Как это сделать?

Comment: Метод должен решать конкретную задачу, и задача этого метода - писать файл. Он не должен знать о том, в каком контексте вызывается. Советую использовать паттерн Listener (слушатель)  с методом onProgress(int progress), реализациями для разных ситуаций и регистрировать слушателей извне.

Comment: @NikolayRomanov Listener или Observer?

Comment: Суть одно и то же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если метод должен работать по-разному взависимости от каких-то *параметров*, то это ни что иное, как передать их, как *параметры*.

Что если вам понадобится в будущем этот метод в еще одном классе?
Вы будете его снова менять, и учитывать в своих условиях новый класс?

В конкретном вашем случае добавьте параметр `boolean showProgress`, и ориентируйтесь на него.

Comment: Я только, что придумал по другому... Я сделал класс с этим методом - абстрактным и унаследовал от него 2 других и переопределил методы показа в зависимости от того что мне нужно...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, судя по тому, что вы написали, достаточно было добавить параметр, а не создавать еще 2 класса.

Comment: Метод НЕ ДОЛЖЕН работать по-разному. Это хороший источник ошибок. К тому же нет ничего ужаснее чем булевские параметры!!! Почитайте "Чистый код" Мартина.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, это ваше личное мнение, не выдавайте его за факт. Я, кстати, абсолютно с ним не согласен. В самом Android SDK полным-полно методов, которые принимают `boolean` один из параметров.

Comment: Это мнение авторов чистого кода, с которым трудно не согласиться. Представьте, у вас есть метод с названием getConnection(). Из названия понятно, что метод возвращает соединение. Но если в этом методе происходит ещё какая-то магия, то из названия метода это не ясно и даже вводит разработчика в заблуждение. Метод надо или назвать по другому, а это очень длинные и нечитабельные имена, либо разнести по разным методам. Я не насиаиваю, всю программу вообще можно написать в одном методе. Но надо думать и о будущем и о тех, кто будет ваш код читать. А то, что в исходниках полно косяков, так это везде

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець `какая-то магия` должна всего лишь быть документированной, например при помощи Javadoc, после чего она сразу же перестает быть магией. Я предпочитаю правильно называть параметры метода вместо создания десятков методов, которые просто будут выполнять все возможные варианты. Для примера - немного изменю ваш метод `establishConnection()`. Неужели надо создавать отдельный метод для того, чтобы установить соединение с `keep alive`? Или создавать по методу для каждого нужного `timeout`? Будет с десяток методов, которые можно было бы просто заменить двумя параметрами. Я не согласен.

Comment: Если вам так удобнее, то вперёд. По своему опыту, я пришёл к созданию многих, даже однострочных методов. Это помогает потом при рефакторинге, повышает читабельность. На вкус и цвет, как говорится...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець `На вкус и цвет` именно об этом я и написал: `это ваше личное мнение, не выдавайте его за факт.`. Я же на своем опыте убедился в обратном.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, - можно контролировать процесс на этапе вызова метода:

```
setProgress( сОднимПараметром ) // вызов из места 1

setProgress( сОднимПараметром, иСоВторымПараметром ) // из места 2
```

Или то же самое, сОднимПараметром - разного типа; 
И соответственно объявляем два метода `setProgress()`